# Why does the if/else if approach give a wrong answer for the Roman To integer conversion question? This is a question from leetcode

Tags: c++, roman-numerals

This is the question that I am referring to:
https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

And this is the code that I have used for the following:

```
int romanToDecimal(string &str) {
     int num=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
        //three special cases given
        if(str[i]=='I' and str[i++]=='V'){
          num=num+4; 
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
       else if(str[i]=='I' and str[i++]=='X'){
            num=num+9;
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
        else if(str[i]=='X' and str[i++]=='L'){
            num=num+40;
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
        else if(str[i]=='X' and str[i++]=='C'){
            num=num+90;
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
        else if(str[i]=='C' and str[i++]=='D'){
            num=num+400;
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
        else if(str[i]=='C' and str[i++]=='M'){
            num=num+900;
            str.substr(i+2);
        }
        else if(str[i]=='I'){
            num=num+1;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='V'){
            num=num+5;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='X'){
            num=num+10;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='L'){
            num=num+50;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='C'){
            num=num+100;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='D'){
            num=num+500;
        }
        else if(str[i]=='M'){
            num=num+1000;
        }
        
    }
    return num;
}
```

It always ends up giving a wrong answer, not iterating and adding the numbers further. Why?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and [what is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Answer (score 5):

`i++` and `++i` and `i + 1` does three different things.

And because how `i++` works, `str[i]=='I' and str[i++]=='V'` will actually the equivalent to `str[i]=='I' and str[i]=='V'`, which is always `false`.

And `i++` (or `++i`) is totally wrong here, you need `i + 1` and then an increment inside the body of the `if`. As is the call to `substr` which isn't needed, and which *returns* the sub-string anyway, so it doesn't actually do anything useful.

Like for example:

```
if(str[i] == 'I' and str[i + 1] == 'V') {
    num=num + 4; 
    ++i;
}
```

---

As for why `i++` (and `++i`) is wrong inside the condition itself, think about if the condition `str[i]=='I'` is `true` but `str[++i]=='V'` is false... Then you will increase `i` before the next condition is checked:

```
// Begins with i == 0
if(str[i]=='I' and str[++i]=='V') { ... }
// If the above condition is false, this will be checked
// BUT! Here i might be equal to 1 because of the above increment
else if(str[i]=='I' and str[++i]=='X') { ... }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is increased each `if`
this is how it should be

```
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); ){
    .......
    else if(str[i]=='X' and str[i + 1]=='C'){
        num += 90;
        ...
        i += 2;
    }
    ..........
    else i++;
    }
```